# Apache FTP Server: MVN Build Failed on Java 8 (SSL)

Tags: java, apache, maven, ssl, ftp

I am trying to build [Apache FTP Server](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/building.html) on my Arch Linux Box.

OS: Arch Linux 64-Bit (Up-to-date).
Kernel: 4.8.6-1.
Java: Oracle 1.8.0_112.
Maven: 3.3.9.

Both Open-SSL and TLS are installed.

Whenever I run "MVN install" in the build directory, I get the following errors.  I believe the problem is due to Java 8 disabling SSL v3.0 in favor of TLS?  If so, it seems like a bad idea to just compile with an older version of java.  Should this library not be used, or is there a better way to handel this?

```
    Results :

Tests in error: 
  testStoreWithProtPAndReturnToProtCInPassiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testCommandChannel(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testReissueAuth(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testIsSecure(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPInPassiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPInActiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPAndReturnToProtCInActiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testListEmptyDir(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testReceiveEmptyFile(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaExplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testThatDataChannelIsSecure(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithoutProtPInActiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPInPassiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPAndReturnToProtCInPassiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testCommandChannel(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testReissueAuth(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testIsSecure(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPInActiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPAndReturnToProtCInActiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testListEmptyDir(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testReceiveEmptyFile(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitDataChannelTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPAndReturnToProtCInPassiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testCommandChannel(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testReissueAuth(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testIsSecure(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPInPassiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPInActiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testStoreWithProtPAndReturnToProtCInActiveMode(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testListEmptyDir(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
  testReceiveEmptyFile(org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.MinaImplicitSSLTest): No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Tests run: 655, Failures: 0, Errors: 29, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache FtpServer Parent ............................ SUCCESS [  0.452 s]
[INFO] Apache Ftplet API .................................. SUCCESS [  1.085 s]
[INFO] Apache FtpServer Core .............................. FAILURE [ 21.201 s]
[INFO] FtpServer Spring web project example ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] FtpServer OSGi Ftplet service example .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] FtpServer OSGi Spring-DM example ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache FtpServer Examples .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.136 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-05T13:36:47-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) on project ftpserver-core: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/USER/build/ftpserver/core/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ftpserver-core
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a very basic step. The error

```
[INFO] Apache FtpServer Core .............................. FAILURE
```

was due to missing [dependencies.](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/required_dependencies.html)  I downloaded and installedthe [latest source Mina Apache file](https://mina.apache.org/mina-project/downloads.html), which includes Apache Core.  The install now went through without any problems. Horray for simple solutions!